# Intellij ' ' on a new line

Tags: intellij-idea, reformat

for developing I use IntelliJ. Is here anybody who knows if is there configuration how to wrap the division of the text to new line (press enter) that'+' operator will be placed on **the new line**?

I have also next question.

Is there configuration how to freeze my tabs in code? Because when I used it and after that I used **Reformat Code** action, my tabs have been lost.

Thanks

Comment: Would this solve your issue?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408462/intellij-idea-plus-sign-when-string-wrap

Comment: Yes I saw this but it not solve my issue

Comment: check this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408462/intellij-idea-plus-sign-when-string-wrap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The StackoverFlow answer link in @Viliam comment is the correct answer, at least in theory... there is a bug that prevents this from working for Strings: [Settings "Operation sign on next line" does not work for automatically breaking strings](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-80495). I recommend you vote for it.

Answer (score 0):

For tab/space:
open Settings (Ctrl + Alt + S), go to: 
Code Style / Java under Tabs and Indents you have "Use tab character".

For String with + on new line, I searched also this one few weeks ago and didn't find it!

Comment: But I would like to use spaces, no tabs. From my colleague I have exported settings and "string with + on new line" works great, but I dont know by witch check button :(

Comment: Maybe you can reformat your file: ctrl+alt+L on file in file list. For "string with + on new line", I don't know where to change it :(